# Android WebView with Javascript calls behaving oddly

Tags: java, javascript, android

I understand how to call Javascript from my WebView, that isn't the issue.

```
if(javascriptCall!=null){
        String hardCodedexample = "1959602";
        webView.loadUrl("http://myappexample+ username);

        webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + "window.application.relocateTo({location:'patients/details',params:{EMPIID:"+ hardCodedEMPIID +"}})");
    }
```

javascriptCall is a String which is passed to my webview activity. hardCodedEMPIID is just an example for our testing. My problem is that when I allow the app the run normally on the device my javascript method doesn't seem to work. It loads the myappexample and I can't tell what happened with my javascript call.

When I debug the app and single step through the code it properly calls the method. I'm confused on how this is possible? the different between single step and normal execution.

Comment: have you enabled JavaScript on your WebView? I mean - webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)?

Comment: So you are loading some webpage with JavaScript files and then trying to execute JavaScript functions right away? Or is there some code between loadUrl functions?

Comment: That might be a problem since relocateTo function might be not visible as JavaScript files need some time for being loaded

Comment: There is no code between them. I want to call the javascript immediately. Is there a way I can know when javascript is initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` event called by `WebViewClient` ([http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) ) . JavaScript file with your function might not be loaded right away after calling `loadUrl`.